# Diagram a bit cramped

Tags: tikz-pic

I got this codes off an Al bot but they are a bit cramped. I need an edit please

```
\documentclass{standalone}
 \usepackage{tikz}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=1cm}]
\node (A) at (0,4) {Router 1};
\node (B) at (4,4) {Router 2};
\node (C) at (8,4) {Router 3};
\node (D) at (0,0) {Router 4};
\node (E) at (4,0) {Router 5};
\node (F) at (8,0) {Router 6};
\draw (A) -- (B) node[midway, above] {WAN Link 1};
\draw (B) -- (C) node[midway, above] {WAN Link 2};
\draw (A) -- (D) node[midway, left] {WAN Link 3};
\draw (B) -- (E) node[midway, below] {WAN Link 4};
\draw (C) -- (F) node[midway, right] {WAN Link 5};
\draw (D) -- (E) node[midway, below] {WAN Link 6};
\draw (E) -- (F) node[midway, below] {WAN Link 7};
\end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of the result and indicate what you mean? Thank you

Comment: Maybe use `rectangle, rounded corners` rather than `circle` as node shape. You could also scale up the diagram or reduce the font size (e.g. by adding `scale=1.2` or `font=\small` as option to the `tikzpicture` environment).

Comment: Always nice to know somebody takes the trouble to attribute others' code ....

Comment: It's not appropriate to post someone else's code here without providing a reference. Was it taken from this site? Or is this code that someone helped you write (which would be fine). It may help to read the [help section on referencing other work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Comment: I got the codes from an AI.

Comment: @SandyG I got the video from an AI chat bot. Should I have indicated. I made that statement as a joke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you looking for something like this:

[image]

- please, consider received comments
- a (stolen) code fragment without any background what original, complete code try to present is bad starting point for formulating a question
- in my MWE I split nodes of routers style from style of nodes used for labeling of arrows.
- is this enigmatic answer helpful to you? In similar situation we are when reading your question ...

OK, it seems that you liked result and comments ... here is  bit improved code for your diagram. BTW, don't trust to AI to much :-)

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{quotes,
                 shadows}
  
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
every edge/.style = {draw=gray, line width=3pt},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto, font=\small, text width=3em, align=center},
         R/.style = {circle, draw, text width=3.3em, align=center,
                     font=\bfseries, fill=white, drop shadow}
                    ]
  \begin{scope}[nodes=R]
\node (A) at (0,4) {Router 1};
\node (B) at (4,4) {Router 2};
\node (C) at (8,4) {Router 3};
\node (D) at (0,0) {Router 4};
\node (E) at (4,0) {Router 5};
\node (F) at (8,0) {Router 6};
    \end{scope}%
\draw   (A) edge["WAN Link 1"] (B)
        (B) edge["WAN Link 2"] (C)
        (A) edge["WAN Link 3"] (D)
        (B) edge["WAN Link 4"] (E)
        (C) edge["WAN Link 5"] (F)
        (D) edge["WAN Link 6"] (E)
        (E) edge["WAN Link 7"] (F);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]